# Apache2 restart fail with error: "Apache2: bad user name: USERNAME

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I have LAMP server on Ubuntu Server 12.04 on VPS. I am running on it an owncloud 5 instance,  mail server and some simple pure-html sites on virtual hosts. Recently I installed Rainy server for Tomboy sync, but I am not sure if that was the reason for the error:

When I try to restart apache (service apache2 restart) I get error:

```
apache2: bad user name: USERNAME 
Action 'configtest' failed
The apache error log may have more information.
```

But there are no information in /var/logs/apache2/error.log

After google search I was only able to find people reporting similar error with ${APACHE_RUN_USER} instead or "USERNAME" or with some existing username in that place.

But I do not have "USERNAME" user in the system.

in my envvars I have:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

in apache.conf:

```
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
```

but changed to:

```
User www-data
Group www-data
```

still gave the same error.

---

#### Solved:

As suggested by [Vladimir Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695482/vladimir-dimitrov)
I did:

```
grep -r USERNAME *
```

in my Apache folder, which gave result:

```
sites-available/mydomain.com: WSGIDaemonProcess snowy user=USERNAME home=/path/to/snowy sites-enabled/mydomain.com: WSGIDaemonProcess snowy user=USERNAME home=/path/to/snowy
```

and helped my realize, that I left one virtual host file after my experiments with snowy installation.
After removing it, server works fine.

Comment: What happens if you start apache2 manually? (see `man apache2` for the options you'll have to provide).

Comment: try to run `grep -r USERNAME *` in yout apache's folder, do you see any results?

Comment: Also try to run `source envvars` before restart the service

Comment: @VladimirDimitrov Can you post that as an answer so halas can accept it as the best answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check for older or unknown configurations which contain USERNAME by going to apache's folder and run this

`grep -r USERNAME *`

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem! Saved my day!